# (MySQL) Query for Multi Columns with Multi-level Tables?

Tags: mysql, database, select, join

With MySQL, how can i query a column from the table at 3 level depth?
I mean:
`[main table]` ---> `[child table 1]` ---> `[child table 2]`
`> C#1's ID` -------- `> C#2's ID` ------------ `> String Column`

For example:
[**transaction**]
- id
- *bookid* *
- date
- staff

[**book**]
- id
- *authorid* *
- title

[**author**]
- id
- name

By knowing only `transaction.id`, so how can i query for a result including following columns?
.. `transaction.date` , `book.title` , `author.name` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.date,b.title,a.name from book b  
innerjoin transaction t on t.bookid = b.id 
innerjoin author a on b.authorid = a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select transaction.date , book.title , author.name
from transaction
     join book on transaction.bookid=book.id
     join author on book.authorid=author.id
where transaction.id=<id>;
```

See more on joins here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [MySQL join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) syntax.

```
SELECT transaction.date , book.title , author.name 
FROM transaction 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN book ON transaction.bookid=book.id 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN author ON book.authorid=author.id 
WHERE transaction.id={your_transaction_id}
```

I use `OUTER JOIN` because that returns transaction even if book or author was deleted from DB. In this case result will be look like this: `'2011-01-12',NULL,NULL`